# How do I connect to my state by ID params in Redux Toolkit when the data is an object not an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Take a look at my Slice below

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL
const API = `${BASE_URL}/countrymap`

const initialState = {
  mapdata:[],
  status: 'idle',  
  error:null
}

export const fetchMapData = createAsyncThunk(
  'mapdata/fetchMapData', 
  async (id) => { 
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        API,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-API-KEY': KEY,
          },
          params: {
            titleId: id,
          }
        }
      )

      return response.data.Item;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('API call error:', error.message);
    }
  }
)

const mapSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'mapdata',
  initialState,
  reducers:{
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchMapData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'succeeded'
        //This attempt to make it an array failed with the error
        //  that the state is not iterable
        state.mapdata = [action.payload, ...state] 
        console.log("map payload: ", state.mapdata);
      })
  }
})

// SELECTORS
// This works for an array, but the data is originally coming 
//  in as an object instead
export const allMapData = (state, id) => state.mapdata.mapdata.find(item => item.title_id === id); 

export default mapSlice.reducer
```

for reference, look at these two console logs from two different API calls to two different endpoints from two different slices . Except Media is coming back as an array, and map is an object

[image]

I need to either, turn the `state.mapdata` into an Object to I can use the selector the way it is or re-code the selector so that it doesn't use the `.find()` function because that's an array function. But either way, it needs to compare the titleId in the data to the id in the params

Sorry for not providing workable code. I would but there is an insane amount of dependencies here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
state.mapdata = [action.payload, ...state.mapdata]
```

instead of

```
state.mapdata = [action.payload, ...state]
```

Comment: hahaha, oops, I'm sorry. you're right, I understood you wrong lol